# Evaluate the gaussian integral

Tags: integration

I have this integral i am really trying to solve, after doing a lot of research I think I have it down to this one integral:

$$\int{xe^{-ax^2-bx}dx}$$ Equation 1

Now, I have tried to do complete the square which leaves

$$e^{b^2/4a}\int{x*e^{-a(x+b/2a)^2}dx}$$
Equation 2

Any help would be lovely the actual integral I am trying to solve is the first multiplied by $x^3$ so if you think I am going about this incorrectly please give me a better idea.

Comment: Is the original integral definite?

Comment: No it isnt actually, but I am attempting to integrate by parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quite close to the solution.

Perform the change of variable $y=x+\frac{b}{2a}$ and you'll get two familiar terms: one is the derivative of a Gaussian, the other a Gaussian.

Comment: Thank you very much I used not only integrating by substitution but also that substitution itself and obtained an answer.